# Map a function over a string

Tags: haskell, types, map-function

My understanding is that a `String` in Haskell is a list of `Char`acters. So I should be able to map a function `Char -> Whatever` over a string, right?

```
testChar :: Char -> String
testChar c = c:c:[]

myFunc :: String -> String
myFunc str = map testChar str

main = do
    putStrLn $ myFunc "hi"
```

When I run this i get:

```
 Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
    Expected type: Char -> Char
      Actual type: Char -> String
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘testChar’
    In the expression: map testChar str
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ghci` is your friend:

```
Prelude> let testChar c = c:c:[]
Prelude> let myFunc str = map testChar str
Prelude> :t myFunc
myFunc :: [a] -> [[a]]
Prelude> myFunc "abc"
["aa","bb","cc"]
```

Contrast with:

```
Prelude> let myFunc' str = concatMap testChar str
Prelude> :t myFunc'
myFunc' :: [b] -> [b]
Prelude> myFunc' "abc"
"aabbcc"
```

Various equivalent ways to write this function:

```
myFunc' str = concatMap testChar str
myFunc' = concatMap testChar
myFunc' str = str >>= testChar
myFunc' = (>>= testChar)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
testChar :: Char -> String
testChar c = c:c:[]

myFunc :: String -> String
myFunc str = map testChar str
```

These two do not make sense.  `testChar` maps a `Char` to a different type, and you expect `map` to map that function and get the *same* type out the other side?  `myFunc` will actually return a `[[Char]]`, not a `[Char]`/`String`.

Perhaps you meant `concatMap`?